# How to put values in textbox from listbox in jQuery MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I have one Listbox named "List1" and one button says "Append".
I have on textbox named "TextDescription".
I want to put the select values from the listbox to textbox on click of append button.

So can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function. So assuming you have a select with `id="myselect"` and a text input with `id="mytext"` you could do this:

```
var values = $('#myselect').val();
if (values != null) {
    // concatenate the selected values with , so that we can add them to the textbox
    $('#mytext').val(values.join(','));
}
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YTLBP/6/) illustrating it in action.

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov, but i want to add the value in textbox not in listbox

Comment: @Saloni , oops, sorry, I misread your question. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov, When i m using in application then its giving this error  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object"

Comment: @Saloni, the example I provided uses jQuery. Aren't you using this?

Comment: yes i m using jquery but instead of using a tag i m using button

Comment: @Saloni, did you reference jQuery? Because the error you are getting (`'$' is null or undefined`) means that you didn't even included jQuery in your page or you included a wrong location.

Comment: in the master page i m including jquery-1.4.1.min.js file. My other code is working too

Comment: yes u r write i m not including that file. Thanks its working fine now.

Comment: @Saloni, I am glad you could make it work. So if my post was helpful to you please [mark it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: now i m using multiple listboxes let say List1,List2 now i want to add the selected value from both of the list box to the textbox. Can u tell me how to do this

Comment: @Saloni, you could get the values of the two listboxes: `var values1 = $('#list1').val(); var values2 = $('#list2').val();`. Then use you could join them with `,` and append to the textbox.

Comment: how can i join values1 and values2

Comment: @Saloni, like this: `var result = (values1 || []).concat(values2 || []).join(',');`. And then `$('#mytext').val(result);`.

Comment: Saloni , if its working .. plz mark the answer , please give the credit to a person who have helped u in resolving ur issue, i guess u haven't accepted any answer yet even after ur problem has been solved. This is not the right aptitude. Thnx